# The iOS Simulator libSystem was initialized out of order

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios7, xcode5

I encountered this when testing on the iOS Simulator, this is shown in the Debug Console when running an App:

```
The iOS Simulator libSystem was initialized out of order.  This is most often caused by running host executables or inserting host dylibs.  In the future, this will cause an abort.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue is triggered if you enable **Guard Malloc** in the **Diagnostics** Tab under **Memory Management** in case you enabled it in your Scheme.

Just uncheck it and the Simulator will not run into this problem.

This has no problem in the previous iOS 6 Simulator but it seems to be having issues with the iOS 7 simulator. Sometimes it will crash or hang your App from loading at times it will load your App but will still flag this problem or may cause some other issues later during testing. Originally I just ignored it but it has been getting in the way a lot.

Comment: "The iOS Simulator libSystem was initialized out of order.  This is most often caused by running host executables or inserting host dylibs.  In the future, this will cause an abort."

Wondering if this would have a impact on running apps on device, specially the abort part?